# Can I split the message and the stacktrace for throwable in log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

[The documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) says that I can extract the message

> %throwable{short.message} outputs the message.

but what I don't see is how I might be able to do

```
%enc{$ex{short.message}} $ex{stacktrace}
```

such that if this happens somehow, no newlines are printed in the message

```
throw new RuntimeException("my user data\n has newlines");
```

Comment: You want the multi-line stacktrace to be added without newlines? That'll be impossible to read. Besides, there is nothing preventing the `message` from having newlines too.

Comment: No I want to sanitize the message not the stack Trace

Comment: to be more clear, the problem isn't sanitizing the message, it's that I don't know how to sanitize just the message while still also printing the stacktrace

Comment: I don't know of any such feature in log4j2, you would have to implement something yourself such as a [custom layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Layouts).